# automount boot smbfs solaris 11

Tags: solaris, smb

I need to autoboot a smbfs on solaris 11. When I mount on command line I use this command:

mount -F smbfs -o user=weblogic,domain=next //192.168.32.52/Storage  /Storage

I need the row to insert into /etc/vfstab

Thanks.
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

After you have mounted the SMB filesystem, type 'mount -p | grep smb' and copy and paste the output into /etc/vfstab. Just make sure it has all the options you want...

Comment: this is the output:

mount -p | grep smb
//192.168.32.52/Storage - /Storage  smbfs - no rw,nosuid,intr,acl,xattr

If I run mount -a , the smbfs doesn't mount

Comment: The entry looks good to me, although you need to change the "no" to "yes" for this to work, and if you want to auto mount at boot time. You can use "mountall -F smbfs" just to mount samba FS. Both mountall and mount -a only work with mounts set to mount at boot. If you don't want that type "mount /Storage". Hope this helps...